# React JS Not Read and Write to localStorage in useEffect No Errors

Tags: reactjs

Ultimate goal is to store the JSON data. That way, if the same github user is sent to the GitHubUser component, instead of making a fresh call to the API, it should load the details from the local storage, preventing a network call.

Key Points about the problem.

- do a simple fetch from github public api (no issues, working fine)
- store the data to local storage with the github username as key (not working)
- retrieve the data from local storage by providing a github username as key (not working)
- display json data after render is complete using useEffect (working fine)

I get no errors of any kind with localStorage but nothing gets saved. I have tried this on both Firefox and Edge. The network call happens on every change of login, for the same user, which it should not.

Further, this code is from a textbook I am following, and this is a exact copy from the page that discusses fetch and useEffect. The author goes on to explain that it should work and so far the book has been correct with no errors.

I have put the code in a sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-http-8f2cs

Also, the specific code below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const loadJSON = key =>
  key && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
const saveJSON = (key, data) =>
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));

function GitHubUser({ login }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(
    loadJSON(`user:${login}`)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data) return;
    if (data.login === login) return;
    const { name, avatar_url, location } = data;
    saveJSON(`user:${login}`, {
      name,
      login,
      avatar_url,
      location
    });
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!login) return;
    if (data && data.login === login) return;
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(setData)
      .catch(console.error);
  }, [login]);

  if (data)
    return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;

  return null;
}

//Jay-study-nildana
//MoonHighway
export default function App() {
  return <GitHubUser login="Jay-study-nildana" />;
}
```

Note : I get a couple of warnings related to useEffect but I have already isolated that they are not the issue but I dont think they are the problem. it simple tells me not to use a dependency array since there is only one element for both useEffects. I am using the array on purpose.

**Update 1**

One thing I noticed is, in developer tools, nothing is getting stored in Local Storage after a successfull call to the API. So, right now, I am thinking, saving is not working. Unless I get that working and see the stored data in developer tools, I wont know if load is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if the initial state is the result of some computation, you may provide a function instead, which will be executed only on the initial render:

```
// instead of this
const [data, setData] = useState(
  loadJSON(`user:${login}`)
);

// you better have this
const [data, setData] = useState(() => {
  return loadJSON(`user:${login}`);
});
```

Second, you can achieve what you need with this single `useEffect`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(() => { return loadJSON(`user:${login}`); });

useEffect(() => {
  if (!data) {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((val) => {
      saveJSON(`user:${login}`, val); // put data into localStorage
      setData(val); // update React's component state
    })
    .catch(console.error);
  }
});

if (data) return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;

return <div>no data</div>;
```

You will get your data in `localStorage`. Don't forget that you need to use key `user:${login}` if you need to get it from there.

Comment: i am not looking to improve the use of useEffect. Primarily because, the rest of the chapter makes separate modifications to the two useEffects, so them being intact is important and essential in my current learning situation. the first part, I will give it a go and see if it solves my problem. will update soon.

Comment: I just realized, I cannot focus on Load until save works. I have updated the question with some additional details. I am beginning to think that there is something about localstorage that is not right here.

Comment: You get nothing in `localStorage` because you never put something to it. Your second `useEffect` runs and fetches data - and you update component’s state (setData). Your first `useEffect` does nothing because of this line: `if (data.login=== login) return`. saveJSON is simply never called.